# Removing 'index.html' from my re-directed PHP website url

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, deployment, routes

I'm using Heroku to deploy my site and have tricked it into thinking my static site is a dynamic one by including an index.php file that simply routes to my index.html. I've done this in order to simply host my site on Heroku, which apparently does not normally host static sites, just dynamic ones (to my knowledge).

QUESTION: How can I remove the index.html that comes out at the end of my website: **[www.roberttassy.co/index.html](http://www.roberttassy.co)**? In my code, I have an index.php file has the code block:

`<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>`

which successfully re-routes to my index.html file, but I just don't want "index.html" to come out in my url in the address bar. I would like it to just read: **www.roberttassy.co**. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings follow the above settings and create an apache based server and then use .htaccees file to rewrite the urls, just google it its very easy!

Comment: Thanks! I found using replacing my php code with <?php require("index.html"); ?> to be much easier ;-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with this

```
<?php include 'index.html';?>
```

Comment: Gave you the green check instead since it required slightly less code, hehe.

Comment: lesser code? in what way lol, you could remove my brackets and it would be the same

Comment: Why didn't you submit it like that then?! Bottom line: it's less code.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this instead.

`<?php require("index.html"); ?>` instead of header.