# HTML URL shortcuts instead of page name

Tags: php, html

I am not exactly sure the exact words to google.
How do I rename the url link to a simpler one for my webpages?

example:

**from:**

```
websitename.com/about_us_what_we_do.php
```

**to:**

```
websitename.com/what-we-do
```

- another example is to let the homepage just show the address

**from:**

```
websitename.com/main.php
```

**to**

```
websitename.com/
```

Comment: if you just have files, rename them, if you have loader\router the answer rill depend on how that works

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37289113/

Answer (score 2):

You can use url rewriting using `.htaccess`

In .htaccess you have to mention the url that what you want & which will redirect you to actual page.

Exp :

browser url will be:   domain_name/what-we-do
& Actual url will be : domain_name/about_us_what_we_do.php

in .htacces you have to mention :

```
RewriteRule ^what-we-do$ /about_us_what_we_do.php [L]
```

Check this ref: 
[I have short the URL Using .htaccess but every shortened URL goes to the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095990/i-have-short-the-url-using-htaccess-but-every-shortened-url-goes-to-the-same-pa/55096135#55096135)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a subfolder with the name **what-we-do**
and renaming your file **about_us_what_we_do.php** to **index.php**.

Then, you'll have your site root directory. Inside you'll have a folder named **what-we-do** with an *index.php* file inside.

If you want to do things right, you should look into [VirtualHosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) ( assuming you're managing the Apache server)